# How to Re-render Component Only Once after the data is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to React JS. I am making CRUD Operation in React. Everything is fine but when I delete the item from the list I have to refresh the browser tho update the List. How can I solve this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { Segment, Item, Container, Card, Icon, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { IEmployee } from '../../src/Model/activity'
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';


interface DetailParams {
    id: string;
}


const EmployeeList : React.FC<RouteComponentProps<DetailParams>> = ({ match, history }) => {

    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState<IEmployee[]>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://localhost:44353/Employee/GetEmployeeList')
            .then((response) => {
                setEmployees(response.data)
            })
    }, [])


    const deleteEmployee =(id: string) => {
        axios.get(`https://localhost:44353/Employee/DeleteEmployee/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
            history.push('/employeeList')
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
            <Segment>
                {
                    employees.map(employee => (
                            <Card key={employee.id}>
                                {/* <Image src='/images/avatar/large/daniel.jpg' wrapped ui={false} /> */}
                                <Card.Content>
                                    <Card.Header>{employee.firstName}</Card.Header>
                                    <Card.Meta>{employee.address}</Card.Meta>
                                        <Card.Description>
                                     {employee.organization}
                                </Card.Description>
                                </Card.Content>

                             <Card.Content>
                             
                             
                             <Button
                               
                                onClick={() => deleteEmployee(employee.id)}
                                floated="right"
                                content="Delete"
                                color="red" />

                             <Button
                                as={Link} to={`/edit/${employee.id}`}
                                floated="right"
                                content="View"
                                color="blue" />

                             </Card.Content>

                            </Card>
                    ))
                }
            </Segment>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default EmployeeList
```

The above code is of EmployeeList Component which is routed by  ** /employeeList ** . Here is the UI of the code
[image]

when I delete the item from the list I need to reload the browser to update the List. I tried using employee dependent in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://localhost:44353/Employee/GetEmployeeList')
            .then((response) => {
                setEmployees(response.data)
            })
    }, [employees])
```

this worked fine but the API method is executing infinitely. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why do you have to refresh the page?  Why not just call `setEmployees` in the `deleteEmployee` function, which will update your state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things can be done

1. if your delete api returns the updated data you can just call `setEmployess` and set the updated value .
2. or you can filter the deleted value from the state `employees`

   ```
   const deleteEmployee =(id: string) => {
    //add this in axios call success
        let updatedEmployee = [...employees];
        updatedEmployee.filter(eachEmployee=>eachEmployee.id !== id);
        setEmployees(updatedEmployee);


    }
   ```

Comment: glad that i could help !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of refreshing the page you should just make another request after the delete request to get an updated employees list.

```
const deleteEmployee = async (id: string) => {
    // Delete employee
    await axios.get(`https://localhost:44353/Employee/DeleteEmployee/${id}`)
    
    // Get a fresh list 
    const employees = (await axios.get('https://localhost:44353/Employee/GetEmployeeList')).data
    setEmployees(employees)
    
    // Navigate
    history.push('/employeeList')

}
```

Comment: For some reason I never thought of making another request for data and just wanted to point this answer out to anyone stuck with a similar problem.